# Shell script value issue

Tags: shell

Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/sh
grep $ `date +%Y%m%d`/filename.txt | sed 1d
```

pretty simple. I am looking to be able to run the script with just a value after it, where the value should replace the "$", such as:

```
bash-4.1$ ./script.sh | "value"
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. The notation `./script.sh | "value"` will run your script with no arguments and send the standard output to a program `value`.  You can use `./script.sh "value"` to pass `value` as `$1` to the shell script (so you'd replace the `$` with `$1`).  If you want to search for a pipe symbol followed by 'value', then you'd need `./script.sh '| value'` with the pipe inside quotes.

Comment: ...by the way, if you want a good place to start learning bash (rather than guessing at syntax), I'd suggest http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Answer (score 2):

Use `$1`, and run it as `./yourscript value`.

That is to say:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -e "$1" "$(date +%Y%m%d)/filename.txt"
```

...and...

```
$ ./yourscript "value"
```

The pipe construct isn't appropriate here -- it's used when you connect the output of one process to the input of another.

See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments